# HTML form - If one of these 3 fields is filled, all should be filled

Tags: html, forms

I have a HTML form with 3 required fields and 6 optionals fields. How can I achieve that if one of these 3 fields (street, npa, locality) is filled, force the user to fill the three? It's quite strange that if a user can fill his street address but not his ZIP/NPA code.

I can't figuring out how I could do that.

```
<hr />
<h3>Required fields</h3>
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Pr&eacute;nom" required="required"/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Nom" required="required"/>
<input type="mail" name="email" placeholder="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required="required"/>

<h3>Optional fields</h3>
<hr />
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titre"/>
<input type="text" name="region" placeholder="R&eacute;gion"/>
<div> <!-- if one of these 3 fields (street, npa, locality) is filled, force the user to fill the three--> 
    <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="Rue/n&deg;"/>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
        <input type="text" name="npa" placeholder="NPA" style="width: 48%; margin-right: 2%; float: left;"/>
        <input type="text" name="locality" placeholder="Localit&eacute;" style="width: 48%; margin-left: 2%;"/>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="text" value="+41 " name="phone" placeholder="T&eacute;l&eacute;phone"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes on @Siphalor's answer and I found what I needed. Below is the edited script that works form me:

```
function doInputRequireGroups()
{
  var groups = document.getElementsByClassName("input-require-group");

  for(var i=0; i < groups.length; i++)
  {
     let inputs = groups[i].getElementsByTagName("input");

     for(var j=0; j < inputs.length; j++)
     {
       inputs[j].style.color="1px solid green";

       inputs[j].addEventListener("keyup", function()
       {
         //Only remove the required attribut if all the fields are empty.
         if(inputs[0].value=="" && inputs[1].value=="" && inputs[2].value=="")
         {
           for(var k=0; k < inputs.length; k++)
           {
             inputs[k].required=false;
           }
         }
         else
         {
            for(var k=0; k < inputs.length; k++)
            {
              inputs[k].required=true;
            }
         }
       });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a JavaScript solution because that seems to be the only way. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tua3fxvq/3/)

You just have to bind the script inside a `<script>` tag and call the function `doInputRequireGroups` via `<body onload="doInputRequireGroups();">`.

Then you can group inputs by adding the `input-require-group` class to a container element like you can see in the JSFiddle.

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
function doInputRequireGroups(){
  var groups = document.getElementsByClassName("input-require-group");
  for(var i=0; i < groups.length; i++){
     let inputs = groups[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
     for(var j=0; j < inputs.length; j++){
       inputs[j].style.color="1px solid green";
       inputs[j].addEventListener("keyup", function(){
         if(this.value==""){
           for(var k=0; k < inputs.length; k++){
             inputs[k].required=false;
           }
         } else {
            for(var k=0; k < inputs.length; k++){
              inputs[k].required=true;
            }
         }
       });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i thought

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll try it at as soon as I can but it looks like exactly what I needed!